# how to calculate root hash in MPT?

Tags: raw-transaction, hash, merkle-patricia-tries

I already know how to build an MPT, but don't know how to compute root hash, especially how to deal with the leaf nodes.

I would be grateful for specific examples.

Comment: Does this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39915/ethereum-merkle-patricia-trie-extension-node help?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I still want to know how to calculate node hash，like leaf , branch and extension. This answer doesn't describe what exactly elements are involved in the hash calculation.